# I can call method on current form(first form) before another form(second form) called from side menu

Tags: codenameone

I'm using addSideMenu(this) in every form to add the side menu.Menu items are defined in ENUM MenuOptions. In my case, I want to do some processing on controls before another form gets called from every form. If this is happening through any of the buttons or controls present on the form, then I can do processing and then calling the next form.

I'm having difficulty in doing the same when form is called from Side Menu. I have to do processing based on the elements present in the form and every form has different elements. This cannot be generic method. I don't understand how can I do the same thing, if another form gets called from Side Menu. Please advise.

Example: I'm on form "Start" (First Form) it has buttons "A" and button "B". I call form "Settings" from side Menu --> then I want to access Buttons A and B of form "Start"(first form) before control moves to Settings form.

Code for Side Menu:

```
public static void addSideMenu(Form f) {
Toolbar tb = f.getToolbar();     
Button logout = new Button("Sign Out");
logout.setUIID("SignoutButton");       
for (MenuOptions m : Server.instance.getMenuSortOrder()) { 
m.addToSidemenu(tb);
}
tb.addComponentToSideMenu(logout);
}
```

Code for Side Menu options:

```
public enum MenuOptions {     
SCHEDULE("Sch", "Schedule", FontImage.MATERIAL_PERM_CONTACT_CALENDAR,
e -> new AppointmentsForm(false, true, true, 
Server.AppointmentFolders.APPOINTMENTS).show()),
ACTIVITY("Start", "Activity", FontImage.MATERIAL_ASSIGNMENT,
e -> new ActivityForm("").show()), 
SETTINGS("Settings", "Settings", FontImage.MATERIAL_SETTINGS,
e -> new SettingsForm().show());
}

MenuOptions(String name, String title, char icon, 
ActionListener<ActionEvent> al) {
this.name = name;
this.title = title;
this.icon = icon;
this.al = al;
}

public Component createMenuButton() {
Button b = new Button(title);
if (Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, icon, 20);
} else {
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, icon, 10);
}
Font mediumBoldProportionalFont = 
Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, 
Font.SIZE_MEDIUM);
b.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(mediumBoldProportionalFont);
b.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEtchedRaised());
b.addActionListener(al);
return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the ENUM accepts an action listener. I suggest replacing that with a `LazyValue<Form>` which will create the form lazily for you. Then you can implement an action listener as:

```
Form f = lazy.getValue();
doSomethingOnForm(f);
f.show();
```

Comment: Yes. Enum accepts Action Listener. I have updated the code to give more clarity. I was trying to using LazyVale but didn't find the solutions. As I don't have access to the elements/controls of first form,  how I can I access the elements from Menu Options..

Comment: I have declare this LazyValue in MenuOptions class and replace Action Listener. Correct? But I don't have access to buttons/controls on the form where I'm in before side menu item is clicked. Please advise.

Comment: Since the lazy value returns a Form instance you can manipulate the form at this stage. You can have all the forms implement a common interface with generic methods e.g. `doStuffToControls` and then just invoke that method in the enum code.